# Windows 7 unplanned shutdown

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

I have windows 7, I always set it not to sleep or shutdown, when I come back to work after 24 hours, the PC already shutting , when I turn it on, its looks like forced shutdown, Black screen appear with safe mood option.

how to know what is the cause of the shutdown ? Can I view the cause from logs ?

Comment: Is there any power failure or voltage drop, since it is not a proper shut down.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on `My computer` > `Manage`. The Computer management tool opens up. There, in the left hand pane, click on `Event viewer`. In the event viewer, you can view all system events. Browse through it to find the logs/events you want.

Comment: Event viewer will not be able to record the cause of the forced shutdown, how ever you can view only forced shutdown log "no reason" after you start your computer as " unexpected shutdown" Event ID 6008

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all 
Basically there is power failure , I shift the station to another location and it just works fine